# iframe inside colorbox not accepting submit

Tags: jquery, colorbox

If I remove colorbox from the code below I can submit my form data to the iframe. When the colorbox code is active the form will not submit to the iframe. Colorbox opens, I can see loader.html. No errors in the console. If I call an alert on (document.forms['myForm'].target) I get 'myFrame'. The subm code seems to be called before colorbox opens.

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".openCBX").colorbox({inline:'true',innerWidth:"980",innerHeight:"550"});
});
function subm(x,y) {
document.forms['myForm'].opt1.value=x;
document.forms['myForm'].opt2.value=y;
document.forms['myForm'].target="myFrame";
document.forms['myForm'].submit();
}
</script>

<form name="myF" id="myForm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="opt1" />
<input type="hidden" name="opt2" />

<a class="openCBX" href="#cbx" onclick="subm('opt1','opt2');return false;">open</a>

<div style=\"display:none\"> 
<div id="cbx">
<iframe id="myFrame" name="mFrame" src="loader.html"></iframe>
</div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: onclick will call subm before the .colorbox() function.

Comment: why would that prevent the form from submitting?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I am opening a colorbox that contains inline html. The inline html is a div with a nested iframe. I am submitting form data to this iframe in order to show dynamic results returned from php/mysql in the colorbox lightbox. If I submit to the iframe without colorbox it works, when I enable colorbox the form data will no longer submit to the iframe